# How to retrieve whether database has any tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Knowing to use

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

to query for a list of tables, I'm currently finding no way to retrieve a list of non-system tables only.

I.e. the above query also lists me system tables like "sysdiagrams" or "dtproperties".

**So my question is:**

How to query a database for existance of any user tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following from sys.tables will work. is_ms_shipped defines whether or not the object is a Microsoft table, however sys.tables should contain only user-defined tables

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0
```

To exclude sysdiagrams from the list, here is something I've borrowed from Aaron Bertrand on this [forum](http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/sql-server-tools/t-sysdiagrams-is-marked-as-user-table-557581.html)

```
SELECT o.*
FROM sys.objects o
LEFT OUTER JOIN
sys.extended_properties ep
ON o.[object_id] = ep.major_id
AND ep.class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
AND ep.[name] = 'microsoft_database_tools_support'
WHERE
o.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND ep.major_id IS NULL 
AND type = 'U';
```

You can also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774928/how-to-exclude-system-table-when-querying-sys-tables) on Stack Overflow

Comment: Just tested on a newly created database. The table "sysdiagrams" also appears in that collection (`is_ms_shipped` is "0"). So this seems to not work for me.

Comment: Ah, sysdiagrams is technically not ms_shipped and is a table you create yourself on the database when you create a new DB diagram. 
You have to join to sys.extended_properties to exclude those tables. I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works better than the SO one, since yours also excludes the `dtproperties` table.